# Error en Django "at Reverse for 'task_detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['task/(?P<task_id>[0-9]+)/\\Z']"

Tags: python, base-de-datos, django, formularios

He visto varías veces que es lo que podría estar provocando dicho error, pero en la url de la views "task_detail" no logró encontrar fallo, mucho menos dentro del archivo views.py donde se encuentra la función. Y en el html donde se muestra la url tampoco veo errores, sinceramente no sé que puede ser.

Y lo que percibo es que dice que el "id" no esta vacío, cuando ya rectifique y no es así. Estaré convocando la variable que no es?. Si es así, con que estará haciendo conflictos?. Por favor si alguien me ayuda estaría muy agradecido

````
<pre>{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
</pre>
    <h1>tareas</h1>

    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="{% url 'task_detail' task.id %}"> 
                {% for task in Task  %}
                {% if task.important %}
                    <strong>{{task.title}}</strong>
                {% else %}
                     {{task.title}}
                {% endif %}
                    <p>{{task.description}}</p>
                    <p>{{task.user.username}}</p>
            {% endfor %}
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
<pre>{% endblock %} </pre>

Views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect,get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm  #Importació  para la creación de un formulario hecho en Django
from django.contrib.auth.models import User #Importación para poder guardar y almacenar usuarios  
from django.contrib.auth import login,logout,authenticate #Importación  para crear cookies en los usuarios, tambie´n para cerrar sesion (logout)
from django.db import IntegrityError 
from .forms import taskform
from .models import task
import pdb

# Create your views here.

def Tasks (request):

    #tasks = task.objects.all() #Al hacer esto podemos interactuar con la base de datos, pero al idea es hacer un listado de todas las tareas de un solo usuario, no de todos los usuarios registrados en la base de datos. Así que la función nos permite filtrar de la sguiente forma:
    tasks = task.objects.filter(user = request.user, datecomplated__isnull=True )
    #pdb.set_trace() 
    return render(request,"task.html", {"Task" : tasks})
           
def task_detail(request,task_id):
    task_instancia = get_object_or_404(task, pk=task_id)
    return render(request, 'task_detail.html', {"task" : task_instancia})
           
def created_task(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
         return render(request,"created_task.html",{"form" : taskform})
    else:
        try:
            form = taskform(request.POST)
            new_task = form.save(commit=False)
            new_task.user = request.user
            new_task.save()
            return redirect('Task')
        except ValueError:
            return render(request,"created_task.html",{"form" : taskform, "error" : "Digite valores validos de acuerdo con las casillas"})
        
```

Y el archivo urls.py

```

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from task.views import home,singup,Tasks,cerrar_sesion,singin,created_task,task_detail

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',home,name='home'),
    path('singup/',singup,name='singup'),
    path('task/',Tasks,name='Task'),
    path('task/create',created_task,name='created_task'),
    path('task/<int:task_id>/', task_detail, name='task_detail'),
    path('cerrarsesion/',cerrar_sesion,name='logout'),
    path('singin/',singin,name='singin')
    
]
````

Comment: Hola Mattteuz, no debería ser **<a href="{% url 'task:detail' task.id %}">**?.

Comment: Ya lo intente así como dices, pero me genera el error "'task' is not a registered namespace". 

Lo que pasa es que el 'task_detail' que se ve en la url proviene del parametro que le doy en "name" en rl urls.py. 

` path('task/<int:task_id>/', task_detail, **name='task_detail'**), `

Comment: Pero muchas gracias por responder @Marce Puente ,yo la verdad no tengo ídea de que hacer con el codigo

Comment: Lo que el sistema te dice, es que a **'task_detail'** le falta un parámetro, debe ser algo como **'task_detail:parámetro'**.

Comment: @MarcePuente ya lo había intentado agregandole algún valor al parametro, pero aún así seguía sin funcionar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

task.id esta en blanco porque todavía no lo has leido del query

```
    <li>
        <a href="{% url 'task_detail' task.id %}"> 
            {% for task in Task  %}
            {% if task.important %}
```

ponlo detras del "for" y veras como te funciona

```
    <li>
        
            {% for task in Task  %}
               <a href="{% url 'task_detail' task.id %}"> 
            {% if task.important %}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Afj!. En serio te agradezco, me funciono tal cúal como habías dicho, solo estaba mal acomodado dentro de las etiquetas, ahora puedo seguir con mi trabajo :)